# YouTube Api (V2.0 or 3.0) get channel info given channel url

Tags: php, youtube-api

I've to get 3 simple information from a youtube channel given the channel url.

**Channel url**(example): http://www.youtube.com/user/autocar

**Needed info**: Total videos, subscribers and total views.

I thought that those information should be simple to retrieve thanks to the API. Instead I'm going crazy trying to understand the Google Data documentation.

I'm working with PHP, so I suppose that I could use the php google client. But on the other side I'm pretty sure that to retrieve those simple information I can avoid to use the full library... anyway, someone knows how to get those data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to find the channel id, some URLs come with channel id, some with username.
[Great documentation here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids).

Basically, if it's a

1. Channel id, you already have it.
2. Username, `channels.list(part="id", forUsername="username")`

Once you have the channel id, you'll do a [channel->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) request to get all these details.
[Response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource) will have all the details.

Give it a try with [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it) with a channel id or username.

[PHP Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples/php) to get you started fast.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get all the things you have requested is to search for channel

For instance

```
$channel_query = "channel_name";

$yt_url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?q=".$channel_query."&alt=json&v=2";

$data = file_get_contents($yt_url);

echo "<pre>"; print_r(json_decode($data)); echo "</pre>";
```

After you get the feed, you would need to loop through the channel entries and match your channel. Best way of doing that is using your channel ID.

Comment: I think that it is too generic. If I search for a channel named "Ferrari" I get every channels where the string "Ferrari" appears.

Comment: If you exactly know which channel you are searching for, it'll end up as the 1st result in the entries. Also all the data points you've requested are in that feed. Alternatively, you just use channel feed, but that doesn't give all data you need and is paginated `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channel_name/uploads?v=2&alt=json`

Comment: I think this method is not being used anymore, the example is extremely simple to folloow but I believe Google has changed the method - could you please provide us with the new method / URL?